# Find keywords from data attribute vis using attribute selectors

Tags: jquery, search, attributes, find, selector

I try to do search filter functions via using jQuery and attr selectors like...

```
$('p[data-keywords~="'+keywords+'"]')
$('p[data-keywords*="'+keywords+'"]')
```

**My full code :**

```
function search(keywords) {
    $('p').removeClass('match');

    $('p[data-keywords~="'+keywords+'"]').addClass('match');
    $('p[data-keywords*="'+keywords+'"]').addClass('match');
}


var search_timer;
$("#search").keyup(function() {
    var keywords = $(this).val();
    clearTimeout(search_timer);
    search_timer=setTimeout(function(){
        search(keywords);
    },1000);
});
```

That seems good

but when data is `data-keywords="one two three"`..

and when I put `one three` to search, it's not found

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/dpjky/

Any idea ? or better idea just tell me pls

PS : keyword with another random keyword like `one xxx` will not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query searches for an *exact match*, i.e. "one three" does not exist in "one two three".

jQuery has a nifty multi-attribute syntax that you can use though:
**[Multiple Attribute Selector [name="value"][name2="value2"]](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)**

So first split the string on the spaces, and then create a selector like this:

```
$('p[data-keywords~="one"][data-keywords~="three"]').addClass('match');
```

Comment: @l2aelba Do you want "one xxx" to result in match, yes or no?

Comment: nei :D , coz xxx is another word, will not be found

Comment: Ja, that work, but I using `.not()` so addClass in my real case, anyway It's ok now :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to split your keyword by **space**:

```
function search(keywords) {
    $('p').removeClass('match');

    var keywords = keywords.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, l = keywords.length; i < l; i++) {
         $('p[data-keywords*="'+keywords[i]+'"]').addClass('match');
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dpjky/2/)**

Comment: Good idea , Anyway when I search `one xxx` will not be found, Can you help this ?

Comment: @Gautam3164 `onethree` is just one keyword, so it shouldn't select the row with `one three` within it.

Comment: No you can see onetwothree data-keyword

Comment: No very fixed rule of my search functions , If someone tell better idea I will think about that :D

Comment: @Gautam3164 You mean that `onethree` must select `onetwothree` keyword?

Comment: @l2aelba If you search `one xxx` all rows with keyword `one` or `xxx` will match.

Comment: I think he asked like that only

Comment: @Gautam3164 From question: _but when data is `data-keywords="one two three"` and when I put `one three` to search, it's not found_. In my fiddle this works.